# How to Identify Top Product Combinations from Customer Behavior Data in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, database, numpy, data-science

I'm a data scientist working for a retail company, and I'm trying to analyze customer behavior data to identify patterns and insights that can be used to improve our marketing and sales strategies. Specifically, I have a dataset containing customer behavior data, including the products they have purchased and the dates of their purchases. My task is to analyze the data and identify which products are most frequently purchased together, so that we can create targeted product bundles and promotions to increase sales.

The dataset is stored in a CSV file called "customer_data.csv", and contains the following columns:

- `customer_id`: unique identifier for each customer
- `product_id`: unique identifier for each product
- `purchase_date`: date of purchase in *`YYYY-MM-DD`* format

I'm trying to write a Python script that reads in the "customer_data.csv" file, analyzes the data, and outputs a list of the top 5 product combinations that are most frequently purchased together. I have some experience with Python and have used libraries such as Pandas and Numpy before, but I'm not sure how to approach this specific problem.

Can anyone suggest a Python code solution or algorithm that I can use to identify the top product combinations from the customer behavior data? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated!